# What is the last part in Qt QString Remove?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a code like this:

```
ui->labelRead->setText(QString::fromUtf8(pData).remove(cDataLength.toInt(),8));
```

I read data from stream and put into pData. I know my data length is 16 character. Now in above code there is a number (8). What is it?

When I move my mouse on the number 8, I read as; **(const QRegExp &rx)**

Can someone explain to me what is the last part for?

Comment: There you go: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#remove

Comment: If you use QtCreator: move the cursor to “remove”, press F1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many overloaded implementations of remove

```
QString &   remove(int position, int n)
QString &   remove(QChar ch, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive)
QString &   remove(const QString & str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive)
QString &   remove(const QRegExp & rx)
QString &   remove(const QRegularExpression & re)
```

you can see ***const QRegExp & rx*** because your ide can not resolve your parameters